# Making layout unclickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a layout with parent `FrameLayout` which has 2 child Child1 and Child2.Child1 is visible when the `Activity` starts and as user click on the particular `ImageView` Child2 would be visible. So when Child2 becomes visible all the `View` that are present of Child1 should become unclickable and only `View` on child2 be clickable..

**EDIT**
I have EditText as well so what about them i dont want user to enter any input in them when other layout becomes visible just like what happens when DialogBox becomes visible.!

Answer (score 4):

if you have set `onClick Listener` Event and you want to Remove it , then use : `ButtonOrAnything.setOnClickListener(null);` this will cancel the `OnClick` Even you have Set

Or

You can also use `ButtonOrAnything.setClickable(false);`

Comment: the issue is that i have many views so setting setClicklistener() would not be wise.! and i have `EditText` as well so what about them i dont want user to enter any input in them when other layout becomes visible just like what happens when `DialogBox` becomes visible.!

Comment: I am thinking of same but i was trying to find some other solution if possible. setting Clickable and Enabled property of `Images` and `TextView` as false but if i couuld apply it to the layout that would have been brillant

Comment: i think you can disable Only the Layout that contain all ImageView Button etc ... simply call Layout.setViewVisibility(View.Invisible); Not Sure i think all View in the Layout will be Hidden ...

Answer (score 0):

**-** When child_1 layout is clicked then child_2 should get unclickable using `setClickable(false)` and vice-versa

**Eg:**

```
imageView_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                                child_1.setClickable(true);
                child_2.setClickable(false);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So in case this helps someone, you need to `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` on the FrameLayout that's going to be in front of everything. At least that worked for me. Cheers!